# Getting 403 Forbidden exception while calling the Airport & City Search amadeus self service API from my code with Bearer Auth token

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, resttemplate, bearer-token, amadeus

I am calling the amadeus self-service APIs without the JAVA SDK from a Spring Boot application.
In the first call I am getting the access_token successfully by calling the authorization API. Now with that access_token if I call the Airport & City Search, I am getting this response.

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": 38197,
            "title": "Forbidden",
            "detail": "Access forbidden",
            "status": 403
        }
    ]
}
```

I am passing the access_token as a bearer token in the request header. Below is my code.

```
public String getCityList(String keyword) throws Exception {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setBearerAuth(authToken);
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
        String url = "http://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/reference-data/locations?subType=AIRPORT,CITY&keyword=" + keyword
                + "&page[limit]=5";
        String body = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class).getBody();

        return body;
}
```

The same token is working fine with the Postman.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `http` instead of `https` for the url.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out!!! I was so confused why there was 403 despite sending request as per documentation.